# Twilio - send sms via resources api

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

Hoping the stackoverflow community will help me out. I want to send sms using the POST api in python, here's what i have tried:

```
>> post_data = {"To": "my-phone-number", "From": TWILIO_NUMBER, "Body": "Test message", "AccountSid": "my-account-sid", "AuthToken":"my-auth-token"}
>> import requests
>> response = requests.post('https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/my-account-sid/Messages', data=post_data)
```

I get the following error:

```
response.content     
"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>\n<TwilioResponse><RestException><Code>20003</Code><Detail>Your AccountSid or AuthToken was incorrect.</Detail><Message>Authentication Error - No credentials provided</Message><MoreInfo>https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20003</MoreInfo><Status>401</Status></RestException></TwilioResponse>"
```

I even tried this request URI:

```
>> response = requests.post('https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/my-account-sid:my-auth-token/Messages', data=post_data)
```

Still the same error :-/

Is my uri wrong or the POST parameters incomplete ? Documentation is not great honestly for the POST api :-/

Update: 
Anyone who is still looking for answers, you can either see the accepted answer or update the request as shown below:

```
response = requests.post('https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/my-account-sid/Messages', data=post_data, auth=('my-account-sid', 'my-auth-token'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Sorry you didn't find the documentation great here. Hopefully I can help.

What you are missing is your account SID and auth token as your HTTP Basic Authentication [credentials](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/request#credentials). As the documentation on your [request to the Twilio API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/request#credentials) says, you should be able to provide those credentials in the URL like this:

```
https://{AccountSid}:{AuthToken}@api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts
```

So your original request should look a bit like this:

```
>> response = requests.post('https://{{ account_sid }}:{{ auth_token }}@api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{{ account_sid }}/Messages', data=post_data)
```

As you are using Python, you might find it easier to use the official [Twilio Python helper library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/python). To [send an SMS message](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages) using the library looks a bit like this:

```
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient

account_sid = "{{ account_sid }}"
auth_token  = "{{ auth_token }}"

client = TwilioRestClient(account_sid, auth_token)

message = client.messages.create(body="Hello from Python",
    to= MY_PHONE_NUMBER,
    from_= MY_TWILIO_NUMBER)
```

This way, you don't have to worry about authenticating the request, the `TwilioRestClient` object will do that for you.

Comment: Appreciate it phil. I also found out what was missing in my original query. I added a comment above.